# Unable Deserialize JSON Array to C# object

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I have a HTML page and some Javascript code that is making an AJAX call. On the server side in my API(C#) I am receiving a JSON Array as follows, which can have max 60 elements. For each element I have a class object mapped.

However I am unable to deserialize the array into some any C# object. I have tried Array[], ArrayList and even MyObject[], but nothing.

Can someone please help how I can deserialize each element to MyObject.

I am getting some "illegal character" message when I add breakpoint in Visual Studio and inspect.

```
{[
      {
        "PosX": 1458,
        "PosY": 198,
        "Rotation": 250,
        "Width": 63,
        "Height": 25,
        "URL": "http://localhost:7071/2.png",
        "Name": "10",
        "RawURL": "/Case16/10-2.png",
        "BelongsTo": "k",
        "AppliedRotation": 96,
        "ImageID": 49
      },
      {
        "PosX": 1418,
        "PosY": 563,
        "Rotation": 118,
        "Width": 28,
        "Height": 68,
        "URL": "http://localhost:707/11.png",
        "Name": "10",
        "RawURL": "/Case16/10-1.png",
        "BelongsTo": "karyotype",
        "AppliedRotation": 174,
        "ImageID": 48
      }
    ]}
```

Comment: You need a `key` to map the `array` value at the start of your object
`{data:[....]}`

Comment: I have data.Session which holds the above.

Comment: "{[]}" doesn't seem valid to nest an object and array like that.

Comment: well, thats what i am getting on the server

Comment: Can you try to validate your JSON using a validator like https://jsonlint.com/ ? The JSON snipped you posted is invalid.

Comment: That's not valid json, so you'll need to change the client or trim the json string by hand first.

Comment: what would the valid JSON look like if not above

Comment: Valid Json array would be no leading/trailing { }, just [ ]. Inside an object (as you have it, inside { }) it needs a property. Your Json should look like either `[{object},{object},,...]` or it should look like `{"somePropertyName":[{object},{object},,...]`. Fix the server if you can rather than eg trimming the { } off

Comment: Just because it's not valid JSON, doesn't mean that we should close this post. Lets help by explaining how to deal with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can code/control the server then you should update that logi to produce valid syntax. If you have custom AJAX handling code that is deliberately trying to wrap the response to make it *look* like json when it does not match the pattern of a JSON object, then you should update that logic to inject a property name for the content, *Value* sounds like a good generic name... The other answers will provide further guidance around this.

If however you cannot affect the string and you're stuck with an invalid JSON response, then we can simply sanitize the response in code *before* you try to deserialize it:

```
    string json = @"{[
    {
        ""PosX"": 1458,
        ""PosY"": 198,
        ""Rotation"": 250,
        ""Width"": 63,
        ""Height"": 25,
        ""URL"": ""http://localhost:7071/2.png"",
        ""Name"": ""10"",
        ""RawURL"": ""/Case16/10-2.png"",
        ""BelongsTo"": ""k"",
        ""AppliedRotation"": 96,
        ""ImageID"": 49
    },
    {
        ""PosX"": 1418,
        ""PosY"": 563,
        ""Rotation"": 118,
        ""Width"": 28,
        ""Height"": 68,
        ""URL"": ""http://localhost:707/11.png"",
        ""Name"": ""10"",
        ""RawURL"": ""/Case16/10-1.png"",
        ""BelongsTo"": ""karyotype"",
        ""AppliedRotation"": 174,
        ""ImageID"": 48
    }
]}";

// we don't control this, but server or AJAX callback is wrapping the JSON array as an object.
if (json.StartsWith("{[") && json.EndsWith("]}"))
    json = json.TrimStart('{').TrimEnd('}');

// Now you can try to deserialize:
var list = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ImagePoco>>(json);
foreach(var image in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"[{image.ImageID}] ({image.PosX},{image.PosY}) {image.Name} '{image.URL}'");
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
[49] (1458,198) 10 'http://localhost:7071/2.png'
[48] (1418,563) 10 'http://localhost:707/11.png'
```

---

I verified the above code using this class, you can follow along in this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JK2JAZ

```
public class ImagePoco
{
    public int PosX { get; set; }
    public int PosY { get; set; }
    public int Rotation { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string RawURL { get; set; }
    public string BelongsTo { get; set; }
    public int AppliedRotation { get; set; }
    public int ImageID { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The given structure is not supported in JSON format, which you can validate using any other Json validator tool like [JSON lint](https://jsonlint.com/).

[image]

You can fix this issue by either removing the outer curly bracket "{}" or adding a property ( Eg. "ImageInfo") for the array of objects.

```
{

"ImageInfo":[
  {
    "PosX": 1458,
    "PosY": 198,
    "Rotation": 250,
    "Width": 63,
    "Height": 25,
    "URL": "http://localhost:7071/2.png",
    "Name": "10",
    "RawURL": "/Case16/10-2.png",
    "BelongsTo": "k",
    "AppliedRotation": 96,
    "ImageID": 49
  },
  {
    "PosX": 1418,
    "PosY": 563,
    "Rotation": 118,
    "Width": 28,
    "Height": 68,
    "URL": "http://localhost:707/11.png",
    "Name": "10",
    "RawURL": "/Case16/10-1.png",
    "BelongsTo": "karyotype",
    "AppliedRotation": 174,
    "ImageID": 48
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing the {}

```
[
  {
    "PosX": 1458,
    "PosY": 198,
    "Rotation": 250,
    "Width": 63,
    "Height": 25,
    "URL": "http://localhost:7071/2.png",
    "Name": "10",
    "RawURL": "/Case16/10-2.png",
    "BelongsTo": "k",
    "AppliedRotation": 96,
    "ImageID": 49
  },
  {
    "PosX": 1418,
    "PosY": 563,
    "Rotation": 118,
    "Width": 28,
    "Height": 68,
    "URL": "http://localhost:707/11.png",
    "Name": "10",
    "RawURL": "/Case16/10-1.png",
    "BelongsTo": "karyotype",
    "AppliedRotation": 174,
    "ImageID": 48
  }
]
```

Comment: Or adding a property name

Comment: Yes, so it was the problem with the " {} ". I was able to remove it and then everything worked from there on.